# How can I prevent the ajax call of my Kendo Grid when data i want to pass is null?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid...

```
        <div>
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<xyz.Models.AbcModel>()
                            .Name("myGrid")
                              .Columns(columns =>
                              {
                              columns.Bound(p => p.Name)
                       .Width("5%")

                            .Events(e => e.Change("onChangeUserGrid"))
                            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                            .Input(false)
                            .Numeric(true)
                            .Refresh(true)
                            )
                .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Custom().IconClass("fa fa-user-plus fa-lg ").Name("clickAdd").Text("Add").Action("Add", "My", new { Area = "X" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center; font-size: 17px" }); toolbar.Custom().IconClass("fa fa-user-times fa-lg").Text("Delete").Name("clickDelete").Action("Delete", "My", new { Area = "X" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center; font-size: 17px" }); toolbar.Custom().IconClass("fa fa-search fa-lg").Text("Search").Name("filterUser"); })
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Ajax_Read", "My", new { Area = "X" }).Data("getCurrentGroupIdProperty"))
                    .Events(e => e.RequestStart("onReqStart"))
                    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                    .PageSize(27)
                    )
            )
        </div>
```

...and bound the requestStart event to :

```
function onReqStart(e) {
        if (getCurrentProperty() == null ||typeof getCurrentProperty() == typeof undefined ) {
            console.log("null property")
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
 }
```

But this does not prevent the

> System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'property' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' ...

What I want is that it cancels the request when `property` is null or undefined.

Comment: In some use cases you can set `.AutoBind(false)` to prevent the initial call then control when you want to fetch the data.

Comment: Could you post the entire grid definition? Did you check that `getCurrentProperty()` really retuns `null`?

Comment: it is undefined @CarstenFranke